# Print Composer Grid Coordinate Buffer

Tags: buffer, grids-graticules

Is there a way to create buffer for grid coordinates in Print Composer?  I prefer to add the grid co-ords inside the map but the coords are often overwritten by map data which makes them impossible to read.  Often the coordinates are of more interest to the map reader than the data which overwrites them.  If they were buffered they would be easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, No. There is no option to create a buffer for grid coordinate in print composer. It will be a good idea if this option can be added into QGIS. You can request such as option at [QGIS github](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS) if you like.